# ASPNET Session between jQuery AJAX calls in a CORS enviroment

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, session, cors

Using VS2012, framework 4.5

I have a simple webapp with just a WebService.asmx file. Running the project publishes these 2 webmethods, `SetData` and `GetData`, here's the C# code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://mydomain.com/")]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService: System.Web.Services.WebService {

  [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
  [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
  public string SetData() {
      HttpContext.Current.Session["someData"] = "xxxxxxxxx";
      return "";
  }

  [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
  [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
  public string GetData() {
      if (HttpContext.Current.Session["someData"] == null)
          return "Session NULL";
      else
          return HttpContext.Current.Session["someData"].ToString();
  }
}
```

The web.config is set to enable CORS and also `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` to enable session sharing

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="null" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>

<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

So the projects runs fine. Now I want to consume these 2 methods from a simple HTML page (the HTML is **NOT** part of the ASPNET project, is just an HTML file... thus the CORS problem)
Here's the HTML code (left out the HTML tags for simplicity, but it's just an empty page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:62776/WebService.asmx/SetData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert('SetData OK');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:62776/WebService.asmx/GetData",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    //async: true, -- makes no difference
                    //beforeSend: function(xhr){
                    //    xhr.withCredentials = true;
                    //},
                    success: function(msg) {
                        alert('GetData: ' + msg.d);
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        alert("GetData: Unavailable");
                    }
                });

            },
            error: function(e){
                alert("SetData: Unavailable");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Running the HTML pages gives me `SetData OK` and then `GetData: Session NULL` but I want **`GetData: xxxxxx`**

So my question is, how can I access the same `Session Object` between CORS calls?

I also tried enabling authentication, thinking that ASPNET AUTH COOKIES will somehow keep the correct session ID between AJAX calls, but it didn't work. There is a possible approach using SOAP envelopes to authenticate each AJAX call and send session info, but that seems overkill.

Comment: Have you taken a look at IRequireSessionState? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to set withCredentials which means the client wants implicit "stuff" to be sent (which includes cookies):

http://brockallen.com/2012/12/15/cors-and-windows-authentication/

Also, given that you need "credentials" to be allowed, the server must respond with Access-Control-Allow-Origin with the specific origin requesting -- it can't use "*".

Comment: Thanks, already tried and didn't work. The problem here is not authentication. I'm also aware you can't have both Origin=* and Credentials and the same time. Origin=* is the only way to go since CORS origins are unknown, much like went you publish an open API, you don't know from what domains it will be accessed.

Comment: Hmm, well the only thing I can think of is that the request that issues the cookie also requires withCredentials.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried following adding to your web.config file

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

or add following code to your web method:

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string HelloWorld()
{
   return "Hello World";
}
```

use this to call your service (javascript):

```
function SendAjaxRequest(url) {

var xmlhttp = "";

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    //when response is ready
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var rspText = xmlhttp.responseText;
        if (rspText != undefined) {
            // here is the response
            var json = JSON.parse(rspText);
        }
    }
}

   xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

if you notice the returned data would be wrap in tag to remove it and just get the data use this function:

```
function TrimXmlTag(start, responseText) {

   var from = responseText.indexOf(start),
       remaining = responseText.substring(from, responseText.length - 9);

   return remaining;
}
```

and just change this line:

```
 var json = JSON.parse(TrimXmlTag("[",rspText));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Nick: i had a same problem with calling asp.net webservice through $.ajax()  try adding this to your webservice method HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); ... after messing with it i just solved it using XmlHttpRequest

Comment: @marverick I don't think this `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");` will work on Linux and Macs browsers. The idea is to access the webservice via standard HTML5 on any platform (Win / Mac/ *nix / iOS / Android / BB10 / etc)