# ASP.NET Failed to consume WebMethod using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, webforms, webmethod

I created a simple WebMethod to get the size of a file on remote server. JavaScript message shows always "failed". What did i miss?

**TEST.ASPX.CS**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetRecordingFileSize(string url)
{
    try
    {
        WebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        var response = wr.GetResponse();
        return response.ContentLength.ToString();
    }
    catch (WebException webException)
    {
        return webException.ToString();
    }
}
```

**TEST.ASPX**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "TEST.aspx/GetRecordingFileSize",
    data: "{ url : '" + $('#txtSoundFile').val() + "' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("okay");
        $("#soundFile").attr("src", "Images/check.png");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert("not okay");
        $("#soundFile").attr("src", "Images/error.png");
    }
});
```

Comment: When you debug in the .cs file, is the request coming there? is the url you sent from js file coming correctly to the GetRecordingFileSize method?

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901825/aspnet-session-between-jquery-ajax-calls-in-a-cors-enviroment/17999886#17999886

i hope it helps.

Comment: You may want to check error you get by alerting it client side..and if you're using jquery 1.8+, you should use .done or .always instead of .success as it is deprecated. Please check [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `POST` instead of `GET`. This [post](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) has got nice example.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "TEST.aspx/GetRecordingFileSize",
    data: "{ url : '" + $('#txtSoundFile').val() + "' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("okay");
        $("#soundFile").attr("src", "Images/check.png");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert("not okay");
        $("#soundFile").attr("src", "Images/error.png");
    }
});
```

If you need to use GET then you would have to have [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]

```
 [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
 public static string GetRecordingFileSize(string url)
 {
       //your code
 }
```